# Drag and drop in jstree

Tags: jquery, jstree

I would like to know if it is posible to get an array of the ul list being sorted. As it is for now i get the sortorder of the element being draged. But is this posible?

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you keep the original question and then post your own answer ....

Comment: Done by your request ;o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this to get it working. I don't know if this is the right way, but it works

```
.bind("move_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    //--- Get parent <li>'s id
    var parent = data.rslt.np.attr("id");

    //--- Find all <li>'s within the ul beeing sorted
    var sortOrderList = $('#' + parent + ' ul:first > li').map(function (i, n) {
        return $(n).attr('id').replace("li_", "");
    }).get().join(',');

    data.rslt.o.each(function (i) {
        //--- Server side action goes here
    });
});
```

Hope this can help others